# How do I add a fade to a change image mouseover event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my Javascript function so far :

```
function changeImg (){
    document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/map/maphv.png')"
}

function changeBack () {
    document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/map/map.png')"
}
```

This is in the HTML :

```
<div id="main"> 
    <a data-title="Africa" href="collection/africa.html" onmouseover="mouseoversound.playclip();changeImg()" onmouseout="changeBack()"><img class="africa" src="./img/map/africa.png" height="50"/> </a>
```

This is the CSS :

```
#main {
 background-image: url(../img/map/map.png);
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 100%;
 height: 580px;
 position: relative;
 }

#main img.africa {
 top: 244px;
 left: 397px;
 height: 33.5%;
 position: absolute;
 width: 18%;
 opacity:0;
 }


#main img.africa:hover {
 top: 244px;
 left: 397px;
 height: 33.5%;
 position: absolute;
 width: 18%;
 opacity:1;
 transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
 }
```

So the CSS is quite irrelevant but I posted it so that you can see how the top hover is fading in and out. I just wanted to add the fade to the onmouseover event to the background map main element.

So really I just need to add the fade in the Javascript function and add that function to the mouseover event handler?

Any ideas as Javascript is not my first language.. ;)

Comment: Can you use Jquery??

Comment: Very basically.. like linking the files in the head and editing a few parameters depending upon what the code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery,then you can do something like

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4b56n6p1/3/)**

```
$("#main").on("mouseenter", function () {

    $(".africa").stop(true, true).fadeOut(); /***fadeIn or fadeOut***/

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I have added the code above between the script tags of my javascript function. Do I need to add or link a Jquery file in the head to make it work?

Comment: Yes to need to link jquery. If your javascript code is working,even this should work. Here is link if you want <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Richa.. It still doesnt seem to work as you can see here http://www.sbwebworks.co.za/test/map.html

Comment: You sure you added jquery link.?? It shows empty in console. Also make sure id and class is correct

Comment: It is working right?? You want fade other when you hover Africa??

Comment: Yes.. I want to fade the background (grey map) when you hover over africa.. So the background fade is not working.. and suggestions?

Comment: Richa you see at the moment the africa section fades using my css but i want the background to fade between images.. right now it just switches them.. there must be a way to fiddle that code you suggested to do this using Jquery.

Comment: Hi @Richa You there? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**Ditch the Javascript**

If i understand your question correctly, you want to fade between images when you hover over an element, right? This can easily be done in pure CSS.

- Give the element you want to animate a background image
- Add a child element that's the same size as the parent. This can be an `<img>`, or a span or div with a background image
- Set the opacity for the child element to 0, unless someone hovers over the parent element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="fading-bg">
    <img src="foo/bar.jpg" alt="stuff">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fading-bg{
    position:relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.fading-bg img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}

.fading-bg:hover img{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Javascript is awesome, but in my personal opinion you should avoid using it for simple animations like this, as CSS is more than capable of doing it on its own.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. but the reason why I have included the javascript event on top of the CSS is that when the absolutely positioned anchor/button is hovered over.. I want the entire background image behind that to change image by fading in.